# Accessing the map of only the desired country with ArcGIS map

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am new in this field. I want to use ArcGIS map to access a map that shows the borders of only a certain country, for example the Netherlands, and then work on the map only for that country, but I could not understand how I can access the map of only a certain country with ArcGIS. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you are asking about a map service, and want it to only display one country, then that's on the service, not the client. It's conceivable that, without annotation, and with the same exact boundary you could render non-country polygons in a background color, but it's likely to be hideous.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a selection, but only if you are accessing a feature access web service or the data directly. If you are using a map service you can use an identify, and then create a bookmark, but it's not ideal. But each time that you select the bookmark after creating, it will zoom to just that country.

If you have the data to direct access then open the attribute table, and in the upper right-hand corner there is a menu. Click the menu and choose "Select By Attributes". In the "Select By Attributes" dialog box you can choose the Attribute that has the name of the country. For instance "NAME" = 'CountryName', then click apply. The selection after it is created, will highlight the borders of the country that you entered.